# Fetching file path from a Perl '.rc' file

Tags: perl, dynamic, path, rc

So I have a Perl '.rc' file (let's call it 'path.rc' with Perl syntax) which has this line:

```
$RC{model_root} = '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_fabric_00011/abc_rel//xy/xy-abc1-15aa05e'
```

I need to fetch the files from directory `'xy-abc1-15aa05e'`. I am not supposed to hard code this path in my Perl file (let's call this `'Fetch.pl'`) as the path may change frequently, so there's a separate .rc file maintained. I'm using:

```
my $model_root = $RC{model_root};
```

to link to the path in my Perl code (like a parameter to link to the path in rc file). How do I now open the files in directory `'xy-abc1-15aa05e'`? My Perl file is not able to get the path :(

This is breaking the rest of my code... How can I to do this?

Comment: There is a ton of information missing to be able to answer this question, but the solution you perhaps should be using is to use a proper serialization format if you have a settings file.

Comment: So on the high level, this '.rc' file has a path that I'm trying to fetch / access from my perl code to open files located in that path. The perl file is not able to access it. Does that make it sound a little clear?

Comment: And the '.rc' file has nothing other than that one line: $RC{model_root} = '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_fabric_00011/abc_rel//xy/xy-abc1-15aa05e'

Comment: Does the .rc file have to contain that specific contente?

Comment: No, the .rc file needn't be in any specific format or anything. It just looks like this:  $RC{model_root} = '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_fabric_00007/psf2_releases//ip/ip-psf2-15ww05e' 

1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your 'rc' file a Perl module like this:

Defs.pm:

```
package Defs;

our $path = '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_fabric_00011/abc_rel//xy/xy-abc1-15aa05e';

1;
```

Then you can - in your script:

```
#Ensure we can 'find' the defs file, by having a library path that's relative to
#the script location.
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;

use Defs;

print $Defs::path, "\n";
```

If you specifically need to use the format you've listed, then you need to process the contents of the file. One way of doing this is with `eval`. But I'm not overly keen on doing that unless absolutely necessary.

You could do something like this though:

```
use Data::Dumper;

open ( my $rcfile, "<", 'rcfile' ) or die $!;
my %RC;
eval <$rcfile>;

print Dumper \%RC;
```

I dislike using eval in this sort of way though - you need to be quite careful about your inputs, because otherwise odd things might break. (Note - this only works for a one line file - if you have multiple lines, you might need to `local $/;` to slurp the whole file to eval it).

I would instead be tempted to use a regular expression to parse:

```
my $model_root;
while ( <$rcfile> ) {
   my ( $varname, $value ) = ( m/\A(\S+) = \'(\S+)\'/ );
   if ( $varname eq '$RC{model_root}' ) { $model_root = $value; }
}

print $model_root;
foreach my $file ( glob "$model_root/*" ) {
    print "Doing something with $file\n";
}
```

Comment: with the use of regular expression in your example, $value must have the complete path ('/nfs/fm/disks/fm_fabric_00011/abc_rel//xy/xy-abc1-15aa05e'), right? From here, I would need to go into the dir: '/xy-abc1-15aa05e' and open files. Do you think I must use another while loop and pattern match there?

Comment: Yes, that's what's extracted into `$value`. Treat it as a directory, and `glob` it: `foreach my $file ( glob "$value/*" ) { #do something }`

Comment: The regular expression approach in your example was really helpful! (Output: Doing something with /prod
              Doing something with /proj) I am now able to connect to the directory 'xy-abc1-15aa05e' and see the files in it. I should be able to use regular file opening and handling codes to read these files, right?

Comment: Yup. All the usual open/close/read options will work. One of the advantages of 'glob' is that it returns full file paths. (opendir doesn't).

Comment: @Sobrique..I'm confused with the output I get..I tried changing the path in my rc file today and I get the same print msg: "Doing something with $file\n" with the same directory names. On a closer look, I think the directories at every level of the path are being fetched and not the files from the last directory. That is, for '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_fabric_00011/abc_rel//xy/xy-abc1-15aa05e' , I wanted only files within 'xy-abc1-15aa05e' to be read, but the code is opening files and directories from each level : /nfs../fm../disks..' etc. Any idea how this can be avoided?

Comment: It'll print everything that matches that 'glob'. Try echoing the string, and see what you get.

Comment: I echoed it and I see that it prints all the directories like this: '..(prints everything here)../..(prints everything here)..nfs..(prints everything here)../..(prints everything here)..fm..(prints everything here)../' but does not get into the final directory which is 'xy-abc1-15aa05e'.

Comment: OK. It _shouldn't_ be. That's probably worth posting as a new question (referencing this one)

Comment: Hm..that's what I was thinking.Probably this one's going off topic. The solution you gave was definitely useful but I don't completely understand the 'glob' function. Will start a new post then.